# ASP.NET Cannot insert the value NULL into column ‘name’

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, sqldatasource

I have One `Users` table, columns: `id`, `name`, `surname`. I am trying to make simple insert functionality, but when I submit form I get **Cannot insert the value NULL into column ‘name’, table ‘database_name.dbo.Users’; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.**

I am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insert(v=vs.110).aspx) tutorial.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="Spravochnik.Users.test" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyPlaceHolder" runat="server">

<script runat="server">
    private void store(object source, EventArgs e) {
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
    }
</script>

<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceMode="DataReader" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-FJR7LSU;Initial Catalog=spravochnik;Integrated Security=True"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Users"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Users (name, surname) VALUES (@Name, @Surname)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter Name="Name" FormField="NameBox" />
            <asp:FormParameter Name="Surname" FormField="SurnameBox" />
        </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:TextBox ID="NameBox" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="NameBox"
    Display="Static"
    ErrorMessage="Please Enter User's Name." /><br />

<asp:TextBox ID="SurnameBox" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="SurnameBox"
    Display="Static"
    ErrorMessage="Please Enter User's Surname." /><br />

<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="store" />


</asp:Content>
```

**Site.Master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Spravochnik.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Public/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div style="padding-top:50px">
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Public/js/jquery.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Public/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help, ***Thanks*** in advance!

Comment: The value is what i have entered in `name` input (not empty)

Comment: Have you disabled viewstate?

Comment: @mjwills No, I didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why but when I merge Master and child pages to a single one, it works fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hiii,

1.you can change the schema of your database , you can set Identity value and increase the identity seed to +1.
[image]

2.you can manually assign some values for the data column ID.

3.You can remove select allow nulls in your table.

Comment: This is one way, I guess it depends if the issues is that it won't allow an insert of NULL, or if it is trying to insert NULL

Comment: ID field is not an issue, it is auto-incrementing. The problem is **name** and  **surname** fields when I call store method it is not getting those values and I don't know why.

Comment: I don't want **name** and **surname** to be **null**

Comment: Check if the textbox names are correct. Or remove the textbox and put a new one, give a specific name and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NameBox" runat="server" />
```

to:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="NameBox" runat="server" />
```

and change:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="store" />
```

to:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="store" />
</form>
```

*This is needed since `asp:FormParameter` needs a `<form>` and your HTML lacks one as is.*